# 404 page not found Core Controller constructor doesn't work and the rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**Hello everyone, please help me figure it out - here is the startup.cs**

I try to simulate JWT token generatuin.All routings checked and are present.Services too

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {    
            //добавляет контроллеры как зависимости
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRazorPages();    
            var authOptionConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("Auth");    
            //регистрирует данную конфигурацию в контроллерах как зависимость
            services.Configure<AuthOptions>(authOptionConfiguration);
            services.AddMvc();    
            services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                    })
                );
;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }    
            app.UseCors();    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
```

**And this is the code of the class controller itself:**

This controller actions and its constructor should be executed but in fact no

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IOptions<AuthOptions> authOptions;
        public AuthController(IOptions<AuthOptions> authOptions)
        {
            this.authOptions = authOptions;
        }

        private List<Account> Accounts => new List<Account>
        {    
            new Account()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("6DC42CF2-637D-45B1-9CFF-271859151B8B"),
                Email = "user@gmail.com",
                Password = "user",
                Roles = new Role[]{Role.User}
            },
            new Account()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("669DDDD8-3803-4E92-BC08-EBA80DEF35A9"),
                Email = "user2@gmail.com",
                Password = "user2",
                Roles = new Role[]{Role.User}
            },
            new Account()
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("9E0170A7-47CC-4FA3-B7D8-6059E0980B70"),
                Email = "admin@gmail.com",
                Password = "admin",
                Roles = new Role[]{Role.Admin}
            }
        };    
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Login request)
        {
            var user = AuthenticateUser(request.Email, request.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                //Generate JWT
                var token = GenerateJWT(user);

                return Ok(
                    new
                    {
                        access_token = token
                    }
                    );
            }

            return Unathorized();    
        }    
        private IActionResult Unathorized()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private Account AuthenticateUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return Accounts.SingleOrDefault(zx => zx.Email == email && zx.Password == password);
        }

        private string GenerateJWT(Account user)
        {
            //Header
            var authParams = authOptions.Value;

            var securityKey = authParams.GetSymmetricSecurityKey();
            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            //Header

            //PayLoad
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString())
            };

            foreach (var role in user.Roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim("role", role.ToString()));
            }    
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(authParams.Issuer,
                authParams.Audience,
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(authParams.TokenLifetime),
                signingCredentials: credentials);


            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

In fact, I get 404 Page Not Found

> Status Code: 404; Not Found

Comment: What url did you use?